# Proving $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} > \frac{13}{24}$ for $n>1,n\in\Bbb N$ by Induction

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

Proving $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} > \frac{13}{24}$ for $n>1,n\in\Bbb N$

To solve it I used induction but it is leading me nowhere my attempt was as follows:

Lets assume the inequality is true for $n = k$ then we need to prove that it is true for $k+1$

so we need to prove $\frac1{k+2} + \frac1{k+3}+\cdots+\frac1{2(k+1)} > 13/24$

I don't know where to go from here please help.

Comment: you want to solve it using induction?

Comment: Yes I think induction would be appropriate

Comment: what is the set of n? does n belongs to Natural numbers greater than 1 ?

Comment: Yes n belongs to Natural numbers greater than 1

Comment: So what would be a better method?

Comment: @user2189524, I have added an answer using induction.Induction is a legitimate option here. I take back my last comment

Comment: How fast is the number of terms increasing? How fast is the magnitude of the terms decreasing? If you can show the sequence is increasing the rest is trivial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $$f(n)=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}=\sum_{r=1}^{2n}\frac1r-\sum_{s=1}^n\frac1s$$

So, $$f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}>0$$ for integer $n\ge0$

$\displaystyle \implies f(n)$ is an increasing function.

Now, $f(2)=\frac13+\frac14=\frac7{12}>\frac{13}{24}$ as $7\cdot24>12\cdot13$

Comment: I suppose that instead of $\frac 1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{2n}$ you mean $\frac 1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}$, and instead of $\sum\frac1{2n}$ you mean $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac 1k$, and instead of $\sum\frac1{n}$ you mean $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1k$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Thanks

Comment: why f(2) = 1/3+1/4 = 7/12, while f(n) = 1/(n+1)+1/(n+2)+...+1/(2n)

Answer (score 12):

Using induction we first show this is true for $n=2$:

$\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2+2}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{7}{12}=\frac{14}{24}\gt\frac{13}{24}$

Therefore it is indeed true for $n=2$.

Now lets assume it is true for some $n=k$, therefore:

$S_k=\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+...+\frac{1}{2k}\gt\frac{13}{24}$

Finally we need to prove that this implies it is also true for $n=k+1$:

$S_{k+1}=\frac{1}{(k+1)+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)+2}+...+\frac{1}{2(k+1)-2}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)-1}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$
$\qquad=\frac{1}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+3}+...+\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$
$\qquad=-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+3}+...+\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$
$\qquad=-\frac{1}{k+1}+S_k+\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$
$\qquad=S_k+\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}-\frac{1}{k+1}$
$\qquad=S_k+\frac{1}{2(2k+1)(k+1)}$
$\qquad\gt S_k$

$\therefore S_{k+1}\gt \frac{13}{24}$

Answer (score 2):

Your sum ($=:S_n$) can be written as follows:
$$S_n=-{1\over2n}+\left({1\over 2n}+{1\over n+1}+{1\over n+2}+\ldots+{1\over 4n}\right)+{1\over 4n}\ .$$
Now the large parenthesis can be viewed as a trapezoidal sum for the integral $\int_n^{2n}{1\over x}\ dx=\log 2$. Since the function $x\mapsto{1\over x}$ is convex for $x>0$ the trapezoidal sum is greater than the integral; therefore we immediately obtain
$$S_n>\log 2-{1\over 4n}\geq\log2-{1\over8}\doteq0.568\qquad(n\geq2)\ .$$
Since ${13\over24}\doteq0.542$ the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}} =\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\log(2)$$

by Reimann's Definite integrals and this is limiting sum and for all terms ,
 the sum is less than $\log(2)$

and $$\log(2)> \frac{13}{24}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}=H_{2n}-H_n $$
is an increasing function, since
$$ f(n+1)-f(n) = \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}>0. $$
It follows that $\forall n>1,\; f(n)\geq f(2)=\frac{7}{12}>\frac{13}{24}$.
Additionally, by Riemann sums
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}f(n)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\log(2)$$
and
$$ 0< \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3(1-x)^3}{1+x}\,dx = \frac{111}{20}-8\log(2) $$
leads to $\log(2)<\frac{111}{160}$, so:
$$\boxed{ \forall n\geq 2,\quad \color{red}{\frac{7}{12}}\leq\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}<\color{red}{\frac{111}{160}}}$$