# Prove that $\frac 12\leq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac {1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}...+\frac{1}{n+n}$

Tags: inequality, summation, harmonic-numbers

How do I prove $$\frac 12\leq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac {1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}...+\frac{1}{n+n}$$

without using induction? Note that clearly $n\neq 0$

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: @JoshChen Why for $1$?

Comment: @tatan I think you need to check the question. Do we have to disprove the theorem? For n =1 , 1/(n+1) becomes 1/2. All the other terms will just add to it so L.H.S. will be greater than 1/2

Comment: @TonyClayton Yeah...I have given $\leq$ sign...

Comment: You can find several posts showing that this is at least $\frac{13}{24}$. For example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508664/proving-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac12n-frac1324-for

Answer (score 3):

The reverse inequality is true for $n≥1$.

If $1≤k≤n$ then $\frac{1}{n+k}≥\frac{1}{n+n}$. Therfore, you get :

> $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac {1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}...+\frac{1}{n+n} ≥ \frac{1}{n+n}+\frac {1}{n+n}+\frac{1}{n+n}...+\frac{1}{n+n} = n \cdot \frac{1}{n+n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

This inequality does not hold since for any $n\in \mathbb N$ you have 
$$\frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac {1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{n+n}.$$
To see this, note first that any term above is greater than $\frac{1}{n+n}$, so that your sum is greater than $n\cdot \frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}.$