# !How to properly input this query in wolfram alpha?

Tags: induction, wolfram-alpha

The thing I want to input:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2n} > \frac{13}{24}, n>1$$

The best I managed so far:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prove+by+induction+sum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En+1%2F(n%2Bi)+%3E+13%2F24,+n%3E1

But it says it's not true. I can do the first step of the proof and it's true (for n=2).

---

Answer for this problem:

[Wolfram Alpha input and result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508664/proving-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac12n-frac1324-for)

my question is not a duplicate, as it's about wolfram alpha not interpreting this correctly.

Comment: For $n=1$:  ${1\over 1+1}<{13\over 24}$

Comment: It is true for $n> 4 $ ! https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prove+by+induction+sum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En+1%2F(n%2Bi)+%3E+13%2F24,+n%3E4

Comment: This just seems like WA is mistaken to me.

Comment: Related, if you are interested: [Proving $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} \geq \frac{13}{24}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ by Induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508664/proving-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac12n-frac1324-for)

Comment: @Qwerty it's for n>1, I fixed my post, sorry.

Comment: @Marsan For me it says "not always true" ...

Comment: @Watson Yes, that is the same. My question is not a duplicate though, as the question is for wolfram alpha.

Comment: @kok_nikol  This site is about mathematics; the linked answer addresses that.  This site is not about how to enter a question into CAS.

Comment: @amWhy Ok, it's a duplicate then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha gives bizarre answers... Set $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+i}$ We have $S_{n+1}- S_n = + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \geq 0$. Therefore $(S_n)$ is increasing. $S_2 = \frac{7}{12}>\frac{13}{24}$. Hence the result ...

Comment: This is nice and short. Thanks!