# Prove by induction that for any $n \ge 2$ : $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} \ge \frac{13}{24}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

Prove by induction that for any $n \ge 2$ :  $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} \ge \frac{13}{24}$$

I obviously know the base case is true, but beyond that it seems to get convoluted and I'm not sure how to solve this question.

Anyone help?

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this by induction? How does the sum for $n$ differ from the sum for $n+1$? Answer: one term is removed and two are added, so what is the net addition? Is it positive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} > \frac{13}{24}$ for $n > 1,n\in\Bbb N$ by Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508664/proving-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac12n-frac1324-for)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You just need to show
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n+1}  <  \frac{1}{2n+1}  + \frac{1}{2(n+1)}.
\end{eqnarray*}